# Advanced Lua Pattern Matching

Tags: regex, lua, pattern-matching

I would like to know if either/both of these two scenarios are possible in Lua:

I have a string that looks like such: `some_value=averylongintegervalue`

Say I know there are exactly 21 characters after the `=` sign in the string, is there a short way to replace the string `averylongintegervalue` with my own? (i.e. a simpler way than typing out: `string.gsub("some_value=averylongintegervalue", "some_value=.....................", "some_value=anewintegervalue")`

Say we edit the original string to look like such: `some_value=averylongintegervalue&`

Assuming we do not know how many characters is after the `=` sign, is there a way to replace the string in between the `some_value=` and the `&`?

I know this is an oddly specific question but I often find myself needing to perform similar tasks using regex and would like to know how it would be done in Lua using pattern-matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like the following (`%1` refers to the first capture in the pattern, which in this case captures `some_value=`):

```
local str = ("some_value=averylongintegervalue"):gsub("(some_value=)[^&]+", "%1replaced")
```

This should assign `some_value=replaced`.

> Do you know if it is also possible to replace every character between the = and & with a single character repeated (such as a * symbol repeated 21 times instead of a constant string like replaced)?

Yes, but you need to use a function:

```
local str = ("some_value=averylongintegervalue")
  :gsub("(some_value=)([^&]+)", function(a,b) return a..("#"):rep(#b) end)
```

This will assign `some_value=#####################`. If you need to limit this to just one replacement, then add `,1` as the last parameter to gsub (as Wiktor suggested in the comment).

Comment: I think it is OK, but it looks like there should be one replacement here, so a limit argument `1` can be passed to `gsub`.

Comment: Oh that is perfect, thank you! Do you know if it is also possible to replace every character between the `=` and `&` with a single character repeated (such as a * symbol repeated 21 times instead of a constant string like `replaced`)?